# Spring Data - Inheritance Search by Type

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Lets assume we have the entities below:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="Type")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.Joined)
public abstract class Employee extends Persistable<Long> {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    //getters, setters
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class SalariedEmployee extends Employee {
            //various fields
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("C")
public class ContractEmployee extends Employee {
            //various fields
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("H")
public class HourlyEmployee extends Employee {
            //various fields
}
```

And a `Repository`

```
public interface EmployeeRepository implements PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {
}
```

How can I search do a query lets say "Bring me all the Employees that are not HourlyEmployees". Obviously I would require these to be Paged/Sorted so I probably cant do `findAll();` and just remove the entries from the Page collection if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If you want to target a specific type then create a repository for that type. Anything else is a hack, in particular if you start to query by fields of that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the JPQL Type Operator:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#JPQL_special_operators

The JPA 2.0 spec (section 4.6.17.4)  gives the following examples of usage:

```
SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE TYPE(e) IN (Exempt, Contractor)

SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE TYPE(e) IN (:empType1, :empType2)

SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE TYPE(e) IN :empTypes

SELECT TYPE(e)
FROM Employee e
WHERE TYPE(e) <> Exempt
```

Comment: Is there a way to use it with Criteria API?

Comment: See bottom of page: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/path#Entity_Type_Expressions_